# Why is the compiler calling the default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

Why do I receive the error below? (Why is the compiler trying to call the default constructor?)

```
#include <cmath>

template<typename F> struct Foo { Foo(F) { } };

int main()
{
    Foo<double(double)>(sin);   // no appropriate default constructor available
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because there is no difference between

```
 Foo<double(double)>(sin);
```

and

```
 Foo<double(double)> sin;
```

Both declare a variable of name `sin`.

The parens are superfluous.  You can put as many parens as you want.

```
int x;             //declares a variable of name x
int (x);           //declares a variable of name x
int ((x));         //declares a variable of name x
int (((x)));       //declares a variable of name x
int (((((x)))));   //declares a variable of name x
```

All are same!

If you want to create *temporary* instance of the class, passing `sin` as argument to the constructor, then do this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename F> 
struct Foo { Foo(F) { std::cout << "called" << std::endl; } };

int main()
{
    (void)Foo<double(double)>(sin); //expression, not declaration
    (Foo<double(double)>(sin));     //expression, not declaration
    (Foo<double(double)>)(sin);     //expression, not declaration
}
```

Output:

```
called
called
called
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/IjFUe

They work, because all three syntaxes force them to be expressions, rather than *variable* declarations.

However, if you try this (as @fefe sugguested in the comment):

```
 Foo<double(double)>(&sin);  //declaration, expression
```

It is not going to work, for it declares a reference variable, and since it is not initialized, you will get compilation error. See : http://ideone.com/HNt2Z

Comment: O_________O ... [the daily wtf]

Comment: Wow... how do I call the constructor then?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Casting the line to `void` might work as it forces the entire line to be an expression, therefore creating a temporary.

Comment: @bitmask: Never mind, I actually figured out another way -- `Foo<double(double)>::Foo(sin)` also seems to work. Yay.

Comment: I think taking the address of sin explicitly may also solve the problem, like `Foo<double(double)>(&sin)`

Comment: @Mehrdad: Hm, I'm actually going to delete my comment because I'm not sure.

Comment: @fefe: No. That is wrong. It would declare a reference. `Foo<double(double)>(&sin)` is same as `Foo<double(double)> &sin`. And since it is not initialized, you will get compilation error.

Comment: @Mehrdad: How could that work? That is compilation error : http://ideone.com/A6evb

Comment: @Nawaz: Wow, then that's the second one I found today. (The other one was an `An internal error has occurred in the compiler` that I got when specializing a template struct inside another template struct...)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to make a template from a function pointer type. Dunno what double(double) means, but if you really want to refer to function pointer type thats what you should do:

```
Foo<double(*)(double)> SinFoo(sin);
```